# Javascript files not updated in development with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, webpack

I work on a Rails project, using Webpack to bundle the assets. Each time I make a change in JS or CSS, I run `docker-compose exec web bundle exec rake assets:precompile;` to compile all the assets.

After that, I have to restart the docker containers, and run the `docker-compose exec web bundle exec npm run dev;`

Only after that, I can see the change, and it can take up to 10 minutes. What am I missing? How can I speed up my development process?

My docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: '2'
services:
  chromedriver:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
    volumes:
      # use hosts shared memory to prevent crashes
      # https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm



  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:12-3.0
    volumes:
      - ./bin/docker/postgres/init-test-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-test-db.sh
      - .:/project
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10k"
        max-file: "1"

redis:
        image: redis:5.0.5
        logging:
          driver: "json-file"
          options:
            max-size: "10k"
            max-file: "1"
  worker:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - bundle-cache:/usr/local/bundle
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100k"
        max-file: "1"

  web:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - bundle-cache:/usr/local/bundle
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10k"
        max-file: "1"

volumes:
  bundle-cache:
```

Comment: I don't have too much experience with docker but without it, I run the command `bin/webpack-dev-server` to raise a server that watches the js or css changes, recompiles them, and reloads the page

Comment: Please share your `docker-compose.yml` file to help understanding your context

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with a docker-compose, it's really useful to use **volumes** to also change files from your computer, and to start your compose with a `docker-compose up`.

It looks weird to rebuild assets during a development stage. Is it not possible to bypass this step? I don't know about Rails, but in python Django it's possible to "collect the static" only for production.

Answer (score 1):

At the core, there's an issue that's unrelated to Docker: If your app is configured correctly, you shouldn't need to manually compile your assets – ever! And even if you have to, 10 minutes sound like way too much.

So the first thing you should do is make sure the following things:

- Is your app running in the `development` environment (= does `Rails.env` return `development`)? If not, try setting `RAILS_ENV=development` – this can, for instance, be done in the `environment` setting in your `docker-compose.yml` (or alternatively in a `.env.development` file, if you're using the dotenv-rails gem).
- Is ad-hoc asset compilation enabled in the `development` environment? By default, this should be the case, but you might have accidentally/on purpose changed it. Check that `config/environments/development.rb` doesn't contain `config.assets.compile = false` (or, generally, check `Rails.application.config.assets.compile` and potentially even the whole `Rails.application.config.assets` setting).
- Last but not least, as mentioned above, 10 minutes seems like a very long time for asset compilation. I only remember having an asset compilation time this long once – and this was on a Rails 3 app with dozens of gems from rails-assets.org on a free Heroku instance (= super slow in general). So consider checking if you're loading too much stuff and/or libraries that you don't really need in the asset compilation step. One very common offender in my experience is the moment.js library which is extremely huge and is often only loaded for a very limited number of features, which can often be replaced by simpler libraries like date-fns or js-joda.

I'm happy to investigate further and provide more insights, but I think for this you'd have to share more things (e.g. your Gemfile and environment configurations).

As for Docker, when using the asset pipeline (or newer Rails versions' webpack integration), I'd suggest to the compiled assets into volumes, so they're effectively cached. This could be done like so:

```yaml
# in the `web` service:
volumes:
  # for asset pipeline
  - assets:/usr/src/app/public/assets
  # for webpacker
  - packs:/usr/src/app/public/packs
  - packs-test:/usr/src/app/public/packs-test
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have webpack, why not use webpack to compile?

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
```

Also you can add `speed-measure-webpack-plugin` for your webpack to see details of time spend on complie

In your `config/webpack/development.js`

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

const SpeedMeasurePlugin = require('speed-measure-webpack-plugin')
const smp = new SpeedMeasurePlugin()

module.exports = smp.wrap(environment.toWebpackConfig())
```

Last in your application.html.erb make sure to use
`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>`  to link the webpack compiled js

Also you should look into webpack dev server with rails, so you don't need to restart every time you make changes